# How do you access each shape/object individually in SFML for C++

Tags: c++, sfml

I'am looking for a way to make multiple clickable rectangle shapes appear on the users screen using SFML.
 The code that i wrote only works for the last initialized shape and changes the color for all of the squares.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;


int main()
{

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "warships");
    sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
            {
                int x,y;
                y = 50 + 65 * i;
                x = 260 + 80 * j;
                shape.setPosition(x,y);
                window.draw(shape);
            }
        }

        if (shape.getGlobalBounds().contains(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window))) and event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed )
            shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);

        window.display();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's because you have only one shape, which you draw at several positions. Instead, you would need to have 1 shape per "shape drawn", so each can have it's own color and position.

Comment: @laancelot do you suggest  using something like std::vector<sf::RectangleShape shape(sf::Vector2f(50, 50))> bunch_of_shapes; so that there are many shapes?

Comment: A vector of `sf::RectangleShape` objects would definitely be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you create only one RectangleShape and then change it's position. Probably better idea would be to create array of shapes with predefined positions at the begining of your code like this:

```
std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapes;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
    {
        int x,y;
        y = 50 + 65 * i;
        x = 260 + 80 * j;
        shapes.push_back(sf::RectangleShape(sf::Vector(x, y)));
        shapes.back().setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    }
}
```

then in your drawing loop just simply

```
window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

for (auto& shape : shapes)
{
    if (shape.getGlobalBounds().contains(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(window))) and event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed )
        shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);

    window.draw(shape);
}

window.display();
```